# What --virt-type should I use with virt-install?

Tags: linux, virtualization, redhat, kvm-virtualization

When I look at "man virt-install" for Fedora 13 I see

```
  --virt-type
    The hypervisor to install on. Example choices are kvm, qemu, xen, or kqemu.
    Availabile options are listed via 'virsh capabilities'
    in the <domain> tags.
```

But which should I use for which guest OS?

My host is a Fedora 13 with KVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use "**--virt-type qemu**", especially that since qemu 0.10.0 it now uses KVM if available.

If this does not work try "**--virt-type kvm**".

**Qemu, KVM, KQemu** are all virtualizers.

**Qemu** used to provide software virtualization only (comparable to an emulator in some sort), but now (since Qemu 0.10.0) also provides hardware virtualization through KVM (using the AMD-V and VT-x features of nowadays processors) if it is available and installed.

As said above **KVM** provides hardware virtualization (it uses a feature that can be found in recent/new processors).

**KQemu** was a fork of Qemu providing both software and hardware virtualization using KVM. It has been integrated directly into Qemu in version 0.10.0.

Comment: What are the differences of the types: kvm, qemu, and kqemu?

Comment: See answer. I edited it to add the descriptions.